# re-call cookies curl php

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Hello I want to know how can i re-call Facebook cookie. Created by CURL in `PHP`
I Generate cookies using this Code and save this cookie text file into directory. i want to know how can i re-call this cookie file from directory then use it again.

```
function Get_Login($em,$pa,$cookie,$ipku){
$ip = array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ipku", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ipku");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($em).'&pass='.urlencode($pa).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/34.1445; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,
 "https://www.facebook.com");
 $body = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error
  ($ch));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $content);

// find out cookies
preg_match("/set\-cookie:([^\r\n]*)/i", $header, $matches);

// put cookies to subsequent request
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
$cookie = $matches[1];
```